# Ergoemacs C-x and C-c Shortcuts, and Apple Cmd shortcuts

Tags: emacs, ergoemacs

For ergoemacs, what are the C-x and C-c shortcuts re-mapped to?

There doesn't seem to be a page to help people transition from regular emacs to ergoemacs mode. They just have a keyboard picture with everything in it, without any information on C-x and C-c.

Also for Apple keyboards, when it says Ctrl/Cmd, does that mean either can be used? It doesn't look like it. It seems that OS X Cmd shortcuts are taking precedence over the ergoemacs ones. Until Ctrl/Cmd means something else?

Comment: If there's no direct mapping, then you might have to look at things on a per-function basis. Pick a function which is normally bound to one of those prefixes, and use `C-h w` (`whereis`) to ask Ergoemacs which key that function is bound to. If you have a regular Emacs instance running alongside, then you can use `C-h c (key)` in that to give you a function name, and then plug that into `C-h w (function)` in Ergoemacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> is `copy` and <kbd>Ctrl-x</kbd> is `cut`.

According to [ErgoEmacs Documentation](http://www.ergoemacs.org/features.html), the keybindings `C-c` and `C-y` are respectively associated with native `<copy>` and `<paste>` functionality using [emacs](/questions/tagged/emacs) `kill-ring-save` and `yank` commands.

The traditional `C-k` and `C-y` methods of line pulling / yanking used in GNU Emacs and XEmacs are left behind in an attempt to "[make it] so you don't have to change your mindset when you switch in and out of emacs". We can expect many features of [ergoemacs](/questions/tagged/ergoemacs) to be intuitive to the sort of end-users who have never been religiously bound to a text editor.

Comment: I understand this, but that doesn't answer either of my questions: 1- The first being which bindings are now the C-x and C-c prefixes and 2- What about the Alt/Cmd and Ctrl/Cmd syntax used in the documentation?

Comment: I meant that I don't expect (and don't see any evidence of) ErgoEmacs to have parallels to the common Emacs keybinding traditions, rather I think they are intentionally moving in a different direction -- many of us know the traditional keybinding almost as a unique mode of thought or learned cognitive faculty. From what I have seen, ErgoEmacs intends to appeal to a demographic that would not be interested in learning such a thing, if you know what I mean.

Comment: It looks like @miercoledi is right. I don't see anything in the documentation, or a quick scan of the source, to suggest that they've actually moved the original maps bound to C-c and C-x - they just got rid of them completely. I'm surprised someone that likes Emacs enough to put this much work into customizing it *never* uses C-c or C-x.

Comment: Oh, makes sense. And if I were to bind my own shorcuts, then simple shortcuts such as for example C-j for example would be enough (assuming it's not mapped)?  Any ideas about Apple's Cmd?

Answer (score 2):

In current version of ergoemacs-mode, by default C-x and C-c are same as GNU Emacs's.

in older version of ergoemacs-mode, the gnu emacs's C-x and C-c are simply left intact. ergoemacs-mode just turn on cua-mode.